# Dynamically added navigation class doesn't work on localhost?

Tags: php

Was playing with dynamically adding a class to a li in my main navigation server-side.  It works as intended from our live staging site but is not work through localhost using MAMP.  Any ideas why that might be?

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/index-production.php" ? "current" : "");?>"><a href="index-production.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/about.php" ? "current" : "");?>"><a href="about.php">About</a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Live URL Layout:  http://project.domain.com/about.php

Localhost URL Layout: http://localhost:8888/Project%20Name/about.php

The folder name didn't follow my normal naming conventions and therefor has the %20.  Would that stop 'PHP_SELF' from pulling correctly?

Comment: You have two completely different paths involved. You'll need to write a function that strips out your local prefix before testing.

Comment: @tadman - I'm admittedly an absolute novice at PHP, but I was under the impression that ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] effectively listed the file name from the root to begin with.  Shouldn't that negate the need to strip anything before?

Not questioning the accuracy of your comment.  Just trying to understand this at a deeper level than "this works" and "this doesn't"

Comment: I'm just going with what you claimed. For local development I prefer to use tools like [Vagrant](https://vagrantup.com) to have a full server suite available where the environment mirrors the deployment target as closely as possible. If that's not the case you'll need to have a configurable "mount point" which can be stripped: `""` (production) or `"/Project%20Name"` as examples here.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP there's survival guides like [PHP the Right Way](http://phptherightway.com) which can give you insight on a variety of topics. In particular, have a look at things like [frameworks](http://www.phptherightway.com/#frameworks) as a tool to solve this problem. Most have some kind of routing layer which can help in a multitude of ways, especially stripping the unnecessary (and ugly) `.php` from all your URLs.